# Adapting Nested Divs Following Content

Tags: css, html

My problem is that the nested div ('content') does not adapt his height following the real content, in this case my form. So the former div adapts his height but the latter div doesn't do it. How can i resolve this?

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='content'>
        <form action="#" id="admin_form">
           <input type="text" class="input350" name="status" />
           <input type="text" class="input350" name="tlt" />
           <br>
           <input type="text" class="input350"  name="msg" />
           <input type="submit" class="input350" style="float:left;" value="Admin" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #container
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 900px;
        height: auto;
        border:solid 4px #1FC3D2;

    }

#container .content
    {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #EFEFEF;
        width: 898px;
        height:auto;
        border:solid 1px #000;
    }
```

Comment: Height is applied according to the content in it.

Comment: Height is by default auto; you do not need to define it explicitly(yourself). Follow the answer provided. Consider your submit buttons's style is floating. Just remove it and get solved given that you are not doing something wrong in `input350` which we can't see here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last input of your form is floated. Floated elements don't stretch their parent's height.

Adding this to after the form:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from the submit button and add this css

```
input[type="submit"]{
 display:block   
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J9D7Z/)**